# Obfuscation vs Packing

Tags: c#, security, encryption, obfuscation, packing

What is the difference between "Obfuscating" code in my application as opposed to "Packing" it with solutions like Themida?

How are these two terms different when it comes to someone trying to pirate my application?

Edit: Restructured question.

Comment: what do you mean by 'the application would still run however would not be readable' - should it run without your application or should it not?

Comment: Is your end goal to release a product? Do you not want people to have access to the source code? If so, there are better methods than security through obscurity to deal with code pirating.

Comment: Omer, I edited the post.
Blue Ice, yes that's basiscally it, however this is only a self teaching project so I can't afford spending money.

Comment: Your concept is flawed, because an attacker would reverse engineer your 'decrypter' program. Or just wait until the decrypted program is loaded to memory and examine it there. Security isn't something that can be picked up without a lot of research effort. Do the research, then ask a more focused question.

Comment: Dear all, I have restructured the question in an attempt to remedy old mistakes.

Thank you all for providing feedback and criticsm! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to do this without spending money have a look at [Dotfuscator](http://Dotfuscator.com), there is a free edition and comes with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a few separate and unrelated things here. Let's define some terms.

**Obfuscation**

This generally involves automatically renaming as much non-public code as possible. It's still the same code and will run exactly the same way, and it's just as easy to disassemble your program as it was before, but it may delay someone in understanding exactly what the code is doing while they put the pieces together.

**Encryption**

This generally involves translating a sequence of information into another sequence of information. Encrypting a file, such as your assembly, will mean that it can no longer be easily inspected but *it can also no longer be run.* The CLR needs to be able to understand your program, and if it's encrypted then it has no idea what you're trying to say.

So now let's talk about your questions.

> What if I use a program to encrypt my program?

This is a very bad idea. Say you have your encrypted program and your encryptor program. What's to stop somebody from just disassembling the encryptor program, using the same encryption algorithm, keys, salt, etc. and just decrypting your program themselves? Your encrypted data is only as secure as your method of encryption.

> Then how do I stop people from pirating my program?

That's a good question and that's one that quite a few people have been trying to find a solution to for a while now. There are a few paths you can go down, DRM, Licensing Services, or having something that's not actively running on the computer itself (i.e. web software).

If you have a more specific question along one of these topics, you are welcome to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to implement a **plugin architecture**. The decrypt application plugs into the main application.

The main application has an interface `IDecryptor` with a `Decrypt` method.

And the decrypt application has a class `Decryptor` that implements the interface.

The main application checks whether the `IDecryptor` service is registered (a.k.a. plugged in). If it is indeed registered, the `Decrypt` method can be called.

This says nothing about **security** yet. 
It involves algorithms like MD5 and SHA. They take a password and some *salt*. And give you a hash string (looks like random text). You dont save passwords. You save hash strings!

There's a lot to say about security and encryption. This is all I know in a nutshell.

Comment: I would probably avoid mentioning MD5 and 'security' in the same sentence... ;)